# CSS How to attach input box to bottom of divider window

Tags: css

I have a wrapper divider along with a sub-divider for chat window, and an input text box.  But I am not sure how to keep the `input box` underneath the chat window while keeping the `float:left` property, since there will be more than 1 chat window, and I want them to stay next to each other.

Here's a jsfiddle of what I have

http://jsfiddle.net/pu7gK/1/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float`ing the container and removing `float:left` from the `.chat-window` should produce the desired result. The `<div class="chat-window">` default display is `block` so it automatically creates a line break therefore the `<input>` naturally appears below.

Multiple `.chat-tab-container` will float next to each other.

**CSS**

```
.chat-tab-container {
    float:left;
}

.chat-window {
    background:#fff;  
    height:200px;  
    width:250px;  
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;  
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat-tab-container">
    <div class="chat-window"></div>
    <input type="text" class="messages"/>
</div>

<div class="chat-tab-container">
    <div class="chat-window"></div>
    <input type="text" class="messages"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters I would place your text box div inside of your chat box div.
**HTML**

```
  <div class="chat-tab-container">
        <div class="chat-window">
        <input type="text" class="messages"/>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Then you want to get that text box to the bottom of the window
**CSS**

```
 .chat-window
    {
        float:left;
        background:#fff;  
        height:200px;  
        width:250px;  
        border:1px solid #ACD8F0;  
        overflow:scroll;
         position:relative;
    }

    .messages
    {

    position:absolute; bottom:0;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="chat-tab-container">
    <div class="chat-window"></div>
    <input type="text" class="messages"/>
</div>
<div class="chat-tab-container">
    <div class="chat-window"></div>
    <input type="text" class="messages"/>
</div>
```

and

```
.chat-window {
    background:#fff;  
    height:200px;  
    width:250px;  
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;  
    overflow:scroll;
    clear:right;
}

.chat-tab-container { float:left; }
```

... Basically float each container not individual elements - if 'chat-tab-container' should be the top level chat container then have a level in between